# docker. failed to solve executor (exit code: 1)

Tags: golang, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

docker-compose при сборке выдает следующую ошибку:

```
 => CANCELED [5/5] RUN go build -o consumer-app ./cmd/consumer/main.go                                                                                                                                    16.7s
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go build -o producer-app ./cmd/producer/main.go]: exit code: 1
```

Задача запустить два мейника в отдельных контейнерах, но использовать одную и ту же папку для сборки образов.

Мейники лежат по следующей структуре:

**cmd/producer/main.go**

**cmd/consumer/main.go**

Два Dockerfile:

**docker/consumer/Dockerfile**

**docker/producer/Dockerfile**

Dockerfile consumer:

```
FROM golang:1.20

RUN go version
ENV GOPATH=/

COPY ./ ./
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o consumer-app ./cmd/consumer/main.go
CMD ["./consumer-app/cmd/consumer"]
```

Dockerfile producer:

```
FROM golang:1.20

RUN go version
ENV GOPATH=/

COPY ./ ./
RUN go mod download
RUN go build -o producer-app ./cmd/producer/main.go
CMD ["./producer-app/cmd/producer"]
```

В docker compose опущу данные кафки и кипера), опишу что касается двух сервисов.
docker-compose:

```
  consumer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: './docker/consumer/Dockerfile'
    container_name: "consumer"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - broker
  producer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: './docker/producer/Dockerfile'
    container_name: "producer"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - broker
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так??

Comment: Думаю вам стоит для начала попробовать создать контейнер с --volume вашей папки с кодом и попробовать сделать все руками. Так вы увидите более объемное описание ошибки

Comment: Такс, а зачем `GOPATH = /`. Проекты go modules не соберутсявнутри GOPATH.  Вам вообще не нужно указывать эту преременную